# string and Error: new BigNumber() not a number

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, javascript

I am trying to generate a hash of a file and send it to a contract. But I am getting an error

> Error: new BigNumber() not a number: a8fac6cf98e6f5e9a76ae1f8064e505b(…)

Here's my contract code:

```
function sendHash(address student_id, string hash_value) returns(bool sufficient) 
{ 
    student_hashes[student_id] = hash_value;        
    return true; 
}
```

Here's my javascript code

```
function sendHash() {
  getAddresses();
  var meta = MetaCoin.deployed();

  var address = document.getElementById("studentId").value;
  var hash = (document.getElementById("hash").value);
  setStatus("Initiating transaction... (please wait)");

  meta.sendHash(account, hash).then(function() {
    setStatus("Transaction complete!");
  }).catch(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    setStatus("Error sending contract; see log.");
  });
```

I am using datatype 'string' in the contract, but the error says not a number. Have tried different ways, but unable to fix this. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Hi, Can you tell me more about the declaration of the mapping variable `student_hashes` ? Are you using `mapping(address => string) ` or  `mapping(address => uint) ` ?

Comment: Hi @gjeanmart I am using `mapping (address => string) student_hashes;`

Comment: You normally want to store hashes in a bytes32 as the length is fixed and dealing with variable-length strings in Solidity can be a PITA.

Answer (score 1):

I made it work. I didn't reproduce your issue "Error: new BigNumber() not a number:" So in first place, I would recommend to redeploy using

```
truffle migrate --reset
```

Then please below a working code :

**Contract**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;
contract MetaCoin{
    mapping (address => string) student_hashes;
    function sendHash(address student_id, string hash_value) returns(bool sufficient)  { 
        student_hashes[student_id] = hash_value;        
        return true; 
    }
    function getHash(address student_id) constant returns(string hash)  {       
        return student_hashes[student_id]; 
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href="./app.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <script src="./app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Issue</h1>

  <br><label for="address">Address:</label><input type="text" id="studentId"></input>
  <h3>Last hash: <span class="black"><span id="lastHash"></span></span></h3>
  <button id="send" onclick="getHash()">get hash</button>

  <br>
  <h1>Send</h1>
  <br><label for="hash">Hash:</label><input type="text" id="hash"></input>
  <br><br><button id="send" onclick="sendHash()">Send hash</button>
  <br><br>
  <span id="status"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
var accounts;
var account;

function setStatus(message) {
  var status = document.getElementById("status");
  status.innerHTML = message;
};
function getHash() {
  var c = MetaCoin.deployed();

  var address = document.getElementById("studentId").value;

  c.getHash.call(address).then(function(value) {
    var h_element = document.getElementById("lastHash");
    h_element.innerHTML = value.valueOf();
  }).catch(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    setStatus("Error getting Hash; see log.");
  });
};

function sendHash() {
  var c = MetaCoin.deployed();

  var address = document.getElementById("studentId").value;
  var hash = (document.getElementById("hash").value);

  setStatus("Initiating transaction... (please wait)");

  c.sendHash(address, hash).then(function() {
    setStatus("Transaction complete!");
    getHash()
  }).catch(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    setStatus("Error sending hash; see log.");
  });
};

window.onload = function() {
  web3.eth.getAccounts(function(err, accs) {
    if (err != null) {
      alert("There was an error fetching your accounts.");
      return;
    }

    if (accs.length == 0) {
      alert("Couldn't get any accounts! Make sure your Ethereum client is configured correctly.");
      return;
    }

    accounts = accs;
    account = accounts[0];
  });
}
```

Just one remark :
- When you send a transaction, don't forget to add at least {account: %sender address%}